# Page object does not return selector in Playwright

Tags: mocha.js, e2e-testing, playwright

Using Microsoft's playwright, I have this testing code that works:

```
  describe('When a user views a list of forms', () => {
    let rows;

    before(async() => {
      await page.waitForSelector('tbody');
      rows = await page.$$('tr');
    });

    it('should show a table of forms', async() => {
      rows.length.should.equal(11);
    });
```

I would like to break it out into a page object. I have this as my page object

```
class UserFormsPage {
  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
  }

  async rows() {
    await this.page.waitForSelector('tbody');
    return await this.page.$$('tr');
  }       
}
```

And this as my test:

```
describe.only('List Forms Widget', function() {                                                                 
  let page;
  ...

  before(async function() {                                                      
    const context = await this.browser.newContext();                             
    page = await context.newPage();                                              
    const userFormsPage = new UserFormsPage(page);
  ...

  describe('When a user views a list of forms', () => {
    let rows;
     ...

    before(async() => {
      rows = await userFormsPage.rows();
    });                   
            
    it('should show a table of forms', async() => {
      rows.length.should.equal(11);
    });
```

But I get

```
  1) List Forms Widget
       When a user views a list of forms
         "before all" hook for "should show a table of forms":
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined
```

Why is this?

**Note**: using native es modules in Node 16 if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rows()` method is async. Every async method returns a promise, so in your hook, `rows = userFormsPage.rows();` will result only in `Promise { <pending> }`.

If you want the number, you have to await it:

```js
before(async () => {
  rows = await userFormsPage.rows();
});
```

Another problem seems to be that you don't have (at least not here in your question) any creation of the `UserFormsPage` object. The constructor expects `page`, but you don't seem to provide it.

Comment: I correct that but I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined`

Comment: @dman The problem will likely be in `this.page`. I don't see how you create that `UserFormsPage` object, but remember to provide `page` to the constructor (`const userFormsPage = new UserFormsPage(page)` has to be somewhere in your code)

Comment: It is, I just tried to keep the code to minimum in the post

Comment: I just updated the code in the post to show it

Comment: @dman: but `const userFormsPage` seems to be declared in a different scope. `const` and `let` are block scoped in JS, so if you declare it in one `before` hook and try to use it in a different `before` hook, it's not gonna work.

Comment: Oh! That slipped by me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work

`row = await (await userFormsPage.rows());`